# Display Only one value at a time in php

Tags: php

please look at code first and read below:-

when output is  "both" next output also occurs "text"..

1) I want to display output "both" when  $text and $img are set .and  "image" 
only when $img is set  at last "text" only when "$text"  is set

```
if (!empty($text) && !empty($img) ) { echo "both"; }

if (empty($text) && !empty($img) ) {echo "image";}

if (!empty($text) && empty($img) ) {  echo "text";}
```

Please help me teachers.....

Comment: do you know that && is use for true, how it is possible one is set you get output different

Comment: This works as you described. https://3v4l.org/uV1g0 (I kinda mucked up the output).

Answer (score 0):

use `isset` and to execute one condition use `if else`

```
<?php
if (isset($text) && isset($img)) { echo "both"; }

if (isset($img)) {echo "image";}

if (isset($text) ) {  echo "text";}
```

To check empty value you can use

```
if (!empty($text) && !empty($img)&&isset($text) && isset($img)) {
       echo "both"; 
    } else if (!empty($img)&&isset($img)) {
       echo "image";
     } 
     else if (!empty($text)&&isset($text) ) {
       echo "text";
}
```

Comment: `isset` is redundant if you use `!empty`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($img))
{
    if(isset($text))
    {
        echo "Both";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Image";
    }
}
else if(isset($text))
{
    if(isset($img))
    {
        echo "Both";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Text";
    }
}
```

This will work for you..this would be easy to understand too

or else your way

```
if(isset($img) && isset($text))
{
    echo "Both";
}
else if(isset($img))
{
    echo "Image";
}
else if(isset($text))
{
    echo "Text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and short

```
echo  (isset($text) && isset($img) ? 'both' :(isset($text) ? $text : (isset($img) ? $img : '')));
```